# Discriminating Unions using interfaces

Tags: typescript, union-types

I want to override an interface from a module but use some sort of discriminating unions using `interfaces`

```js
export type CellValue = string | number | boolean | Media | null | undefined;

declare module '@tanstack/react-table' {
  interface ColumnMeta<TData extends RowData, TValue extends CellValue> {
    type?: 'text' | 'number' | 'date' | 'select' | 'file';
    options?: Option[] | string[] | readonly string[];
    updateColumn?: (currentValue: TValue, value: TValue) => TValue;
    inputAttributes?: React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;
  }
}
```

where i want the type `TValue` to change depending on the type of `type`

so when `type` is 'file' then `TValue` should be of type `Media` and the rest are like so:

```js
type TypeMap = {
  text: string;
  number: number;
  date: string;
  select: string;
};
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Please [edit] this code to be a self-contained [mre] without reference to external libraries unless your question is *about* those libraries.  An interface cannot be a union at all, so on the face of it what you want is not possible. But unless there's a [mre] here we can easily play with in our own IDEs we can't say for sure or suggest an alternative.

Comment: @jcalz well my question is about overriding a specific library interface, so it has to reference that library

Comment: Then could you tag it as such and make it obvious at the top that you need people with expertise on that library?  But I suspect it only "has to" reference that library because you need that for your use case.  But for a Stack Overflow question it should be more general than that, and then maybe you could get an answer which you *apply* to your use case. Stack Overflow is meant to be useful for future readers as well, not just the person who asked the question.  If you can build a self-contained [mre] that captures the relevant aspects of what you're trying to do, it will help.